# output files in git repository with bash

Tags: git, bash

I tried to output files in a git repository with bash in the way:

```
#!/bin/bash    

files=$(git ls-files -z)

while IFS='' read -r -d '' file
do
  echo "filename: $file"
done < <(printf '%s' "$files")
```

But it doesn't provide any. Can you please help me to find the problem?

Comment: so your problem is that the output is not getting written in the file? also i have to guess that as long as you are using printf you are in a awk-nawk?? please post the whole script so we can see the whole format.

Comment: @hedgehog sorry: there's no output and I'm using bash (edited question)

Comment: maybe i am wrong about this, but i really dont see you writting any output in any file at any point..... maybe its something i dont know of, but when i want to output something on a file i use this format::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: echo "save this" >> /tmp/someFile.txt

Comment: @hedgehog I confused you with my style of debug output prefix '>>>>>' (edited question). I simply want to print all files in my repo into stdout. But I get no output.

Comment: @Noproblem It seems that there's no errors relative to info from this link :)

Comment: I don't know why you need `-d ''` here. `while IFS='' read -r file; do echo "filename: $file"; done < <(git ls-files)` suffices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies not in the `read` but rather in the initial assignment to `files`:

```
bash$ git ls-files -z | wc -c
     301
bash$ files=$(git ls-files -z); echo ${#files}
275
```

Where do you suppose this difference of 26 comes from?  Let's try counting newlines in a plain `git ls-files` (no `-z`):

```
bash$ git ls-files | wc -l
      26
```

Finally:

```
bash$ git ls-files -z | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do echo "file: $file"; done
file: .gitignore
file: COPYRIGHT
[snipped]
```

This all boils down to the fact that bash, internally, cannot store the ASCII NUL bytes in variables.  It just strips them entirely in the `var=$(...)` case.

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Comment: From [this answer in Difference between 'ls' and 'echo $(ls)'](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283589/40596) _$(...) is command substitution and the shell removes trailing newline characters from output of command substitution_. It might be this.

Comment: @fedorqui: no, the shell will replace intermediate (separator) newlines with spaces, but that will maintain the character count, minus the one final newline.  And indeed, `bash$ files=$(git ls-files); echo ${#files}` prints `300`.

Answer (score 1):

For simply listing the file names in bash,

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(git ls-files)

for file in ${files} ; 
do 
    echo $file ; 
done;
```

Comment: This method limits characters that can be used in filenames because they can be interpreted as words delimiters. That's why I tried to use `-z` option of `git ls-files` with combination of bash `read` builtin.